# How to get the Tweet JSON

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a tweet number, how do I get the JSON file from this tweet number?

I was using this code below:

```
# Autenticar com a API do Twitter
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

# Criar uma instância da API do Twitter
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweet = api.get_status("1654136293041864709", tweet_mode="extended")
print(tweet['full_text'])
```

but, from some time to now its getting this error:

Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve

I know that somethings changed in Twitter API
How should I do now?

I tried to get the JSON file from a specific tweet, but its not working anymore.

Comment: Have you tried applying for elevated access?

Comment: i think so, when i look to my dashboard it appears "elevated" in the same line of the project name